# Find more than one smallest submatrices in a big Matrix

Tags: java

I have problem to find a number of the smallest submatrix m in a big matrix M and m=M/2;

I need to find the number of the submatrices in the same loops to find the smallest submatrix 
Here is what I have done.

```
public static void FindSmalSubMatrix(int mat3[][],int rows,int colums)
{
    int subm,i,j,temp=0,location1=0,location2=0, min=0;
    ArrayList submin = new ArrayList();
    if(rows>=colums)
      subm=colums/2;
    else
      subm= rows/2;
    min= Firstmin(mat3,subm);

    for (i=0;i<rows-subm+1;i++)
      for(j=0;j<colums-subm+1;j++)
      {
          for(int k=i; k <i+subm;k++)
              for (int l =j;l<j+subm;l++)
              {

                 temp=temp+ mat3[k][l];
              }

           if (temp <= min)
           {
               min=temp;
              submin.add(min);

              location1=i;
              location2=j;
           }

           temp=0;
      }
    System.out.println(min+" location is :"+location1+" "+location2);
    for( Object value:submin)
      System.out.print(value); 
}
```

And here is an Example

6 6 4 4 3
2 2 3 3 8
5 0 2 2 5
4 9 2 1 4
1 6 8 1 3
7 location is :2 2

161514977

but I need to print that 
min =7 
Location :1 1 
2 3
0 2

min =7 
Location :2 2 
2 2 
1 2

If anybody can help me I will be greatley appreciate it.

Comment: you need to explain what is wrong with your code, what doesnt work and where we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isnt that bad.
Did you try to debug it and check what is saving to submin?
Cause it looks like 16,15,14,9,7,7  (2 last numbers are good, aren't they?)
What is FirstMin?

```
public static void FindSmalSubMatrix(int mat3[][],int rows,int colums)
{
    int subm,i,j,temp=0,location1=0,location2=0, min=0;
    ArrayList<Point> locations = new ArrayList<Point>();
    if(rows>=colums)
      subm=colums/2;
    else
      subm= rows/2;
    min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (i=0;i<rows-subm+1;i++)
      for(j=0;j<colums-subm+1;j++)
      {
       temp = 0;
          for(int k=i; k <i+subm;k++)
              for (int l =j;l<j+subm;l++)
              {

                 temp=temp+ mat3[k][l];
              }

           if (temp < min)
           {
              locations.clear();  //you dont need data about larger min, right?
               min=temp;

              Point point = new Point(i,j);
              locations.add(point);

           } else (temp == min) {
              Point point = new Point(i,j);
              locations.add(point);

           }

      }
    // And to print use something like these, but its better to create new class
    // which contain location and small matrixes or just use old bigger to print parts
    // for example just print location (min are equal to all result) and using   
    // location print parts from  mat3

}
```

I think i made few mistakes in this example but you will find it ;)
I used Point class just to save locations of the smallest matrix, you can use another class

**EDIT:**
I had to fix it a bit cause my code is ugly (still but anyway...)

Comment: Thank you very much.but I have problem The location array is not going to have just the smallest matrices it will have the location for the matrices before the smallest one.